# How to edit Google Calender event using Zend_Gdata_Calendar class ?

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

When you retrieve data from a calendar you can set the user before the data is retrieved like this

```
$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($this->client, $this->domain);
$calendar_list = $gdataCal->getCalendarListFeed();
$query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser( $username . '%40domain.com');
```

But how can you do this when you want to create/update an event?

```
$service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($this->client, $this->domain);
$event = $service->newEventEntry();
```

There are no methods like `setUser` on any of the objects returned

Answer (score 0):

I have been into similar condition but, the wordaround that I did was :

```
$service->delete($event->getEditLink()-><URL-Of-The-Event>);
```

and later, create another one.

However, that was approximately an year ago. I am not sure if any new functions have come up because, I never needed it after that.

If no one answers, this wordaround has to work for you :)

Comment: could you please explain what you are doing? can't really figure it out :)